# How to switch from POST to GET in PHP CURL

Tags: php, post, curl, get

I have tried switching from a previous Post request to a Get request. Which assumes its a Get but eventually does a post.

I tried the following in PHP :

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
```

What am I missing?

Additional information:
I already have a connection that's setup to do a POST request. That completes successfully but later on when I try to reuse the connection and switch back to GET using the setopts above it still ends up doing a POST internally with incomplete POST headers. The problem is it believes its doing a GET but ends up putting a POST header without the content-length parameter and the connection fails witha 411 ERROR.

Comment: Be careful with Get requests.  Google has fun with them. ;)

Comment: @Chris - a friend discovered that the hard way when he built a site that managed user-contributed content via GET requests. Googlebot happily followed all the 'delete' links, with predictable results.

Comment: Fixed it for me with same origin: Comment out CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS or delete it rather than passing "null".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Solved: The problem lies here:

I set `POST` via both `_CUSTOMREQUEST` and `_POST` and the `_CUSTOMREQUEST` persisted as `POST` while `_POST` switched to `_HTTPGET`. The Server assumed the header from `_CUSTOMREQUEST` to be the right one and came back with a 411.

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
```

Answer (score 121):

Make sure that you're putting your query string at the end of your URL when doing a GET request.

```
$qry_str = "?x=10&y=20";
$ch = curl_init();

// Set query data here with the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/test.php' . $qry_str); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
print $content;
```

With a POST you pass the data via the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option instead
of passing it in the CURLOPT__URL.

```
$qry_str = "x=10&y=20";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/test.php');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);

// Set request method to POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Set query data here with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $qry_str);

$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
print $content;
```

Note from the [`curl_setopt()` docs](http://php.net/curl_setopt) for `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` (emphasis added):

> [Set CURLOPT_HTTPGET equal to] `TRUE` to *reset* the HTTP request method to GET. 
> Since GET is the default, this is only necessary if the request method has been changed.

Comment: That's a pretty evil way to set a timeout of 51 seconds!

Comment: Nice catch @JackGoossen!

Answer (score 60):

Add this before calling curl_exec($curl_handle)

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
```

Answer (score 6):

CURL request by default is GET, you don't have to set any options to make a GET CURL request.

Answer (score 1):

add this based on a condition. Code with this line is a POST request and otherwise It will be  GET by default. Also We can add the parameters at the end of the URL even if it is POST request

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);