# CURL Execution in PHP

Tags: php, curl

```
    $returnurl = "http://clietsite.com:9000/service";
    $curlPost = "rtyinstance=<parent><child>value</child></parent>";
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    if (!$ch1) die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");
    $headerinfo = apache_request_headers();
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $returnurl);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $headerinfo['User-Agent']);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1*60);
    $result = curl_exec($ch1);
    var_dump($result); 
    echo $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch1);
```

The above code returns responseCode 200, var dump prints string(0) "".

when i run in browser (I'm using PHP Version 5.2.17)
like

```
http://clietsite.com:9000/service?instance=<parent><child>value</child></parent>
```

Which successfully returns an xml.  don't know what could be the issue. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Double-check the input you send to that service is in the expected format, e.g. you might want to use an `array` for [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) probably because you don't need to deal with encoding the post values then.

Comment: i defined an array $postArray = array();
       $postArray['rtyinstance'] = $currentXML; and used like curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArray);

Comment: That's probably the input is still wrong, for example, you're making use of POST while the client might expect GET. Understand the difference of the both, those are [different methods (verbs) of a HTTP request](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.1). - You normally use GET *or* POST. If you copy over the wrong code from some other place only because you searched for cURL and PHP you will run into such problems unless you understand what the code is for. Look for a tutorial instead that will spare you the try and error.

Comment: i have used curl before. but i don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: That also depends on the webservice you're making use of. It it does not tell you what's wrong, you need to test and try until success. There are many parameters to change, But using GET looks curcial, so take care you encode the URL correctly. Looks like the service get's not the parameter to operate upon but that's only a guess.

Comment: yes the client saying there are connecting but no paramaters were passed. i used get as said by Dennis Haarbrink(see below).

Comment: Too localized. We can't tell what headers your service depends on. And you made no effort in elaborating.

Comment: I have used $postArray['rtyinstance'] = urlencode($currentXML); but returns empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via cURL you are using POST, while in the browser you issue a GET.

That might be the issue.

To 'convert' to GET, use this code:

```
$encoded_params = urlencode('<parent><child>value</child></parent>');
$returnurl = "http://clietsite.com:9000/service?rtyinstance=" . $encoded_params;
$ch1 = curl_init();
if (!$ch1) die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");
$headerinfo = apache_request_headers();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $returnurl);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $headerinfo['User-Agent']);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1*60);
$result = curl_exec($ch1);
var_dump($result); 
echo $responseCode = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch1);
```

Comment: how do i pass as get fields in curl

Comment: [How to switch from POST to GET in PHP CURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225409/how-to-switch-from-post-to-get-in-php-curl)

Comment: i changed but still returns string(0) "".

Comment: I made a small adjustment that might work. If this doesn't work there is not much more we can do i'm afraid. Is there any way you can supply us with a *real* `$returnurl`?

Comment: Dennis Haarbrink i encoded and sent using get and post both returns empty. unfortunately i can't give you the real url they'll kill me

Comment: Another thing you can do is completely replay the request the browser makes and start deducing from that. Use a program like Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to capture the browser request, copy past the raw data and send that using `fsockopen()`/`fputs()` to the server.

Answer (score -1):

The following URL is not available for me:

```
http://clietsite.com:9000/service?rtyinstance=<parent><child>value</child></parent>
```

Is that website really accessible from outside your computer/network? If you are hosting the script on one server and the website on another it might not work.

Comment: i have specified sample site name and port