# PHP curl and Infusionsoft Cookie

Tags: php, curl, infusionsoft

I have a simple web form that feeds into Infusionsoft. Not my call. I had been submitting it fine with curl to run an AJAX routine, to eliminate then going to Infusionsoft's domain and a thank you page - instead just displaying a thank you/error msg based on the return. All good so far. The problem I've run into is with the affiliate cookies. Apparently each time I set up an affiliate it generates them a url to my sign up form that has their affiliate data in it and sets a cookie in the url (http://www.example.com?p=XXX&w=XXX).

I'm getting that stripped out with my curl routine. How do I keep a 'url cookie' enabled when submitting through curl? I apologize if my terminology is incorrect, this is beyond the scope of what I usually do and would appreciate any correction.

I know it's a `curl_setopt` but don't understand them enough to make a qualified decision. I basically just need it to keep alive the session that was started with the url. I know this post is lacking, but unfortunately so is my understanding.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, as it doesn't sound like you're actually using cookies. You just want to send query parameters, right? Make sure you're using GET instead of POST. (See how options `CURLOPT_POST, FALSE` and `CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE` are used in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225409/how-to-switch-from-post-to-get-in-php-curl).) Does that help, or am I misunderstanding what you're after?

Comment: @Wiseguy - thx for the help, I didn't think it was a cookie in the truest sense either, but that came straight from the horses (IS support) mouth. I'll take a look at the above, again thanks - I appreciate the sharing of knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The affiliate cookie is tied to the infusionsoft.com domain and you can't access that unless your script is on the Infusionsoft domain.  The only other way to do this is to use some hacked version of the instructions on this page - http://kb.infusionsoft.com/index.php?/article/AA-00878/0/How-can-I-track-affiliate-activity-if-I-capture-leads-or-process-orders-through-the-Infusionsoft-API.html

Best,

Jordan

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at that. Out of curiosity for me just beginning to work with IS and you seem to have some experience with it, what is your opinion of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with modern browsers, because you can make a CORS AJAX request to the hosted version of the web form on InfusionSoft's site. You have to mimic all of the form fields and names, including the hidden ones. So you will need to submit the form to their hosted WebForm version and use Firebug or Chrome's dev tools to watch the HTTP request. Then you will have to submit your form, using the same form fields/names to wherever the `action` attribute of their hosted form is pointing via an AJAX request.

I have implemented this successfully using AJAX, it just doesn't work on IE 7, 8, and 9 because of CORS AJAX security issues. My workaround for those browsers is to use cURL as a proxy to submit the form. The only downside for those special case browsers is that they don't receive the cookie that shows which URLs they've visited in their web profile in InfusionSoft.

Comment: Making a CORS request to InfusionSoft's site I reviced an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error...

Comment: @grigno You may have to talk to IFS support, but ours sends a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for our main domain name oursite.com

Comment: Thank you, my server wasn't configured correctly for cors, now it works!