# php curl lib with http GET and form fields?

Tags: php, libcurl

An API I'm trying to program to requires multipart/form-data content with the HTTP GET verb. From the command line I can make this work like this:

`curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -F grant_type=consumer_credentials  -F consumer_key=$key -F consumer_secret=$secret https://example.com/api/AccessToken`

which seems like a contradiction in terms to me, but it actually works, and from what I see tracing it actually uses GET.  I've tried a bunch of things to get this working using PHP's cURL library, but I just can't seem to get it to not use POST, which their servers kick out with an error.

Update to clarify the question: how can I get php's cURL library to do the same thing as that command line?

Comment: You should have searched the site before posting the question.
this post should help you solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225409/how-to-switch-from-post-to-get-in-php-curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are insisting on HTTP **GET**, then just encode the form elements into query parameters on the URL you are GETing and use cURL's standard get options instead of posting multipart/formdata.

Answer (score 0):

> which seems like a contradiction in terms to me, but it actually
>   works, and from what I see tracing it actually uses GET

Not exactly. curl uses a feature of the HTTP/1.1. It inserts additional field to the header `Expect: 100-continue`, on which, if supported by server, server should response by `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue`, which tells the client to continue with its request. This interim response is used to inform the client that the initial part of the request has been received and has not yet been rejected by the server. The client SHOULD continue by sending the remainder of the request or, if the request has already been completed, ignore this response. The server MUST send a final response after the request has been completed.

Comment: Yes, when tracing the command line invocation I do see the continue being exchanged. Still not sure how to get the php cURL lib to do the same thing though.

Comment: @cabbey the problem is that there is nowhere to try the code on :) BTW, are you sure that the problem is with POST request?

Comment: Yeah, it's not exactly a public API. :(  And comparing the network traces, I've ruled out all the other differences. I have a theory I'm trying at the moment though.

Comment: @cabbey        I tried a couple things, php version of curl is dealing only with post, or get. Why won't you use curl from command line? Otherwise you need some kind of class for http request, which can be modified. Or you may write your own code with fsockopen and so on :)

Comment: @cabbey This might help (or, at least, make the life easier).. http://www.php.net/stream_context_create

Comment: yeah, I was deeply tempted to just exec the blasted command line. :)  But our code base has a rather nice wrapper class for cURL, and I really wanted to continue to use it for maintainability. I had an idea over dinner how to beat their stupid IIS server into submission, see the answer I just posted. :))

Answer (score 0):

-X will only change the method keyword, everything else will remain acting the same which in this case (with the -F options) means like multipart formpost.

-F is multipart formpost and you really cannot convert that to a query part in the URL suitable for a typical GET so this was probably not a good idea to start with.

I would *guess* that you actually want to use -d to specify the data to post, and then you use -G to convert that data into a string that gets appended to the URL so that the operation turns out to a nice and clean GET.