# using curl -G flag in php

Tags: php, rest, curl

Here is my curl command:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ..." \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ..." \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Jonathan Walsh"}' \
  --data-urlencode 'count=1' \
  --data-urlencode 'limit=0' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

I am using php.

For the -X, -H I know the equivalent:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore");

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: ...',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ...',
    ));
```

What about the -G, --data flags?

What's the equivalent code?

Comment: The commandline flag `-G` or `--get` means to `Send the -d data with a HTTP GET`. See the [curlopt flag list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to find which parameter represents GET requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For posting the data(you can use array though):

```
$request = 'where={"playerName":"Jonathan Walsh"}&count=1&limit=0';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request);
```

For `https://` in your url

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

To return the date from curl execution

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
```

Finally:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

**UPDATE:**

Didn't check that you are doing `GET` operation. If you do `GET`, then it will be simply

```
$request = 'where={"playerName":"Jonathan Walsh"}&count=1&limit=0';
$url = "http://example.com/" . "?" . $request;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to [How to switch from POST to GET in PHP CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225409/how-to-switch-from-post-to-get-in-php-curl), you should use :

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
```

Recommended read : http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php