# getting data with curl failed

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get the data returned from this [link](https://www.developer.aero/Airport-API/Try-it-Now) with CURL. However, I'm getting `false` as the output.

Here's my code and output:

Code:

```
$url = "https://airport.api.aero/airport/distance/LOS/ABV?user_key=MY_USER_KEY_GOES_HERE&units=mile";
$ch  = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump( curl_getinfo($ch) );

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data);
```

Dump of `curl_getinfo` call

```
array (size=26)
'url' => string 'https://airport.api.aero/airport/distance/LOS/ABV?user_key=MY_USER_KEY&units=mile' (length=102)
'content_type' => null
'http_code' => int 0
'header_size' => int 0
'request_size' => int 0
'filetime' => int -1
'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
'redirect_count' => int 0
'total_time' => float 0.702
'namelookup_time' => float 0.249
'connect_time' => float 0.468
'pretransfer_time' => float 0
'size_upload' => float 0
'size_download' => float 0
'speed_download' => float 0
'speed_upload' => float 0
'download_content_length' => float -1
'upload_content_length' => float -1
'starttransfer_time' => float 0
'redirect_time' => float 0
'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
'primary_ip' => string '107.22.197.175' (length=14)
'certinfo' => 
   array (size=0)
     empty
'primary_port' => int 443
'local_ip' => string '192.168.1.17' (length=12)
'local_port' => int 53767
```

Dump of `$data`

```
boolean false
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068429/using-curl-g-flag-in-php). Since the url was using `https`, I needed to include this option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`. That did it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully send a get request (you should hide your key from your question lol)

Try this:

```
$url = "https://airport.api.aero/airport/distance/LOS/ABV";
$qry_str = "?units=mile&user_key=MY_USER_KEY_GOES_HERE";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $qry_str); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
print $content;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the info about my key being visible. I tried your solution, I got an empty string as the output.

Comment: Try changing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`
I would try some header options too, like user agent and from their api overview "The default response type is JSON. To return the response in XML, set the HTTP Header Accept to application/xml."

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to make a curl request via command line?

i.e `curl 'https://airport.api.aero/airport/distance/LOS/ABV?user_key=MY_USER_KEY_GOES_HERE&units=mile'`