# CURLOPT_POST vs. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS: Is CURLOPT_POST option required?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm new to **cURL** in PHP. I have a question regarding usage of curl options.

Consider two script files: test1.php and test2.php both present in root www. I'm using **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**. The libcurl version for PHP is **7.22.0**.

**Contents of test1.php**

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $post_data = array(
        'firstname' => 'John',
        'lastname' => 'Doe'
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'localhost/test2.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);   //is it optional?
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**Contents of test2.php**

```
<?php 
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

When I execute test1.php via browser, I can see results posted. Now if I remove curl option containing **CURLOPT_POST**, the example still works. Even if I set **CURLOPT_POST** to false, post is performed and result is displayed. So, is that **CURLOPT_POST** not required at all? It looks option `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` takes care of sending data via **POST** without use of `CURLOPT_POST` option. When I print `$_SERVER` in test2.php, request method is always set to `POST` (with or without option `CURLOPT_POST`).

Could anyone please let me know the exact use of `CURLOPT_POST` option? Is it neccessary required for sending data via `POST`?

Comment: Yes.To set the request method 'post' in curl we set the 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);   

and to send data we use a associative array.And if the array is multiminsional then we use json_encode for the inner level.

Comment: Have you read the question properly? I'm not asking what these options CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and CURLOPT_POST do. Have you tried examples that I have mentioned?

Comment: Pro tip for everyone to use: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` automatically implies `CURLOPT_POST = true`; **but** setting `CURLOPT_POST = true` will erase any previous `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS = array(/*...*/)`, causing empty body send (tested on PHP7.4). Convert `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` value to string to workaround this (`CURLOPT_POSTFIELD = http_build_query(array(/*...*/))`).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are correct. **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** implies **CURLOPT_POST**. You don't need to use **CURLOPT_POST** while using **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**. The request method will always be set to POST in this case.

Note that this is in your case as long as you want it to be a ***POST*** request.

If you don't want to be it a ***POST*** request but set **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**, please see this related Q&A:

- [How to switch from POST to GET in PHP CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1225409/367456)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference the API document say this about CURLOPT_POST

---

**Summary:**

*A true parameter tells the library to do a regular HTTP post. This will also make the library use the a "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header. (This is by far the most commonly used POST method).*

*Use the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option to specify what data to post and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE to set the data size. Optionally, you can provide data to POST using the CURLOPT_READFUNCTION and CURLOPT_READDATA options.*

*You can override the default POST Content-Type: header by setting your own with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.*

*Using POST with HTTP 1.1 implies the use of a "Expect: 100-continue" header. You can disable this header with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER as usual.*

*If you use POST to a HTTP 1.1 server, you can send data without knowing the size before starting the POST if you use chunked encoding. You enable this by adding a header like "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER. With HTTP 1.0 or without chunked transfer, you must specify the size in the request.*

*if you have issued a POST request and want to make a HEAD or GET instead, you must explicitly pick the new request type using CURLOPT_NOBODY or CURLOPT_HTTPGET or similar.*

---

I'm testing right now whether setting the CURLOPT_POST to try will override my CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" setting.