# Can libcurl.net be used to post a new page to confluence?

Tags: confluence-rest-api, libcurl.net

I'm just getting started using the REST API to create pages.

I'm trying to configure a basic example and I thought of using libcurl.net to do it.

Does anyone see any reason why that wouldn't work?

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I have so far adapted from the curllib.net "bookpost" example

```
 Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports SeasideResearch.LibCurlNet

Public Class CurlOperations

Public Shared Sub CurlPost()

    Try

        Dim credUserName As String = "username"
        Dim credPassword As String = "password"

        Dim response As String = Nothing
        Dim outputStdErr As Stream = Nothing

        Curl.GlobalInit(CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL)

        Dim easy As Easy
        easy = New Easy

        ' Set up write delegate
        Dim wf As Easy.WriteFunction
        wf = New Easy.WriteFunction(AddressOf OnWriteData)
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wf)

        'Authentication
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLhttpAuth.CURLAUTH_BASIC)
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_USERPWD, credUserName & ":" & credPassword)

        'disable ssl peer verification
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, False)

        'Header
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")

        ' Simple post - with a string
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, WikiTools.CommREST.WebToCF.PostCurl())

        ' and the rest of the cURL options
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_USERAGENT, ".NET Framework Client")
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, "https://domain.com/confluence/rest/api/content/")
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POST, True)

        response = easy.Perform().ToString
        LoggingAndActivites.WriteLog("Response: " & response, GetFunctionName.GetCallerName, True, True)

    Catch ex As Exception

        LoggingAndActivites.WriteLog("Exception: " & ex.ToString, GetFunctionName.GetCallerName, True, True)

    End Try

    Curl.GlobalCleanup()

End Sub

' Called by libcURL.NET when it has data for your program
Public Shared Function OnWriteData(ByVal buf() As Byte, ByVal size As Int32, ByVal nmemb As Int32, ByVal extraData As Object) As Int32

    LoggingAndActivites.WriteLog(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf), GetFunctionName.GetCallerName, True, True)

    Return size * nmemb

End Function

 End Class
```

I am getting connected because if I remove the username and password I get a response through the "onWriteData" function as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at domain.com Port 7080</address>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem now is that if I correctly log on I'm not getting any response other than the "CURLE_OK" from the "easy.Perform()" function.

It's good because I know it's working to some degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it does work

Here is what I added/changed to make the code above work

```
'I added an Slist to store the header items (I only had one)            
Dim slistHeaders As New Slist
slistHeaders.Append("Content-Type: application/json")

'Then I added the slist to the HTTPHEADER
easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slistHeaders)
```

**THINGS TO WATCH FOR:**

(1) The **URL** of course is the **number one thing**

In my case I was using was https://domain.com/confluence/rest/api/content/ because the Confluence Documentation assumes you would be using the root domain name (as did I)

However, what I didn't know was that the URL I was given to test was already directing me into the "confluence" folder.

So my URI needed to be https://domain.com/rest/api/content/ instead

(2) An indicator that your **HTTPHEADER** needs to be put into an Slist is this return from the server: 415 Unsupported Media Type

(3) Be sure **NOT** to use the **CURLOPT_HEADER** property. If you are seeing this header in your responses you need to make sure it's not used:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Sun, 22 May 2016 17:50:32 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Location: 500.en-GB.html
Vary: negotiate,accept-language
TCN: choice
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 7575
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-gb
```

Refer to my post here for an explanation of why: [CURLOPT_HEADER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369935/4831894)

(4) Lastly, when you build your app if you receive this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in libcurl.NET.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

This is caused by libcurl.net process not being cleaned up.

The "cleanup()" method isn't available in the DLL, despite being lsited in the examples.

So instead use **EASY.Dispose()** at the end of your procedure and this error will stop. (I kept the "GlobalCleanup()" method in just for good measure)

(5) Ironically I went the way of using CURL because I thought that the Confluence interface might require it.

But it appears now that it doesn't and that you can simply use the "HttpWebRequest" Class in .NET to get the same results.

However, the Jury is still out because the "lightweight" test server I was assigned to crashed and I'm waiting for them to fix it so I can verify this.

Either Way I hope all this helps someone

M

Comment: One other note, don't use "charset = utf-8" in your content type.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't but in any case it's not needed that I can determine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the libcurl.net docs : http://www.libcurl.org/

> libcurl also supports HTTPS certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, and user+password authentication.

So I guess you should be able to make a REST API call with it. I have used curl (the linux version) to create and update pages, using something like this:

```
curl --globoff --insecure --silent -u username:password -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @body.json confluenceRestAPIURL/pageId
```

where body.json is a file containing the data to update the page.

I wrote a blog about this here: https://javamemento.blogspot.no/2016/05/jira-confluence-3.html

You can get the code here: https://github.com/somaiah/jira-confluence-graphs

Comment: Thanks Somaiah this will come in handy!