# Curl info - Is there any bug in curl_getinfo?

Tags: php, curl

I am getting blank curl response. Please check my curl info

```
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
```

> ```
> Array
>     (
>         [url] => http://aabb.com/api.php
>         [content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8359-1
>         [http_code] => 200
>         [header_size] => 439
>         [request_size] => 361
>         [filetime] => -1
>         [ssl_verify_result] => 0
>         [redirect_count] => 0
>         [total_time] => 1.943
>         [namelookup_time] => 0
>         [connect_time] => 0.734
>         [pretransfer_time] => 0.734
>         [size_upload] => 5049
>         [size_download] => 0
>         [speed_download] => 0
>         [speed_upload] => 2585
>         [download_content_length] => 0
>         [upload_content_length] => 5049
>         [starttransfer_time] => 1.094
>         [redirect_time] => 0
>         [redirect_url] => 
>         [primary_ip] => 31.131.83.86 //gives correct IP
>         [certinfo] => Array
>             (
>             )
>
>         [primary_port] => 80
>         [local_ip] => 132.138.43.36
>         [local_port] => 44146
>     )
> ```

Please help . I am really fed up now. Do you think everything seems okay in this info
My code is below

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://aabb.com/api.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_error($curl)) { 
    print curl_error($curl); 
} else{
    print_r($response);
}
curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);
exit;
```

Comment: 4me everything is okey.

Comment: @cojack : yea but response is blank / empty. I have posted my code too in my question

Comment: What response are you expecting to get?

Comment: @Martin expecting 1 or true

Comment: @Martin `http_build_query` does the escaping automatically.

Comment: @Barmar ahh, sorry I missed that...

Comment: Try to add curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

Comment: @cojack According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728740/curlopt-post-vs-curlopt-postfields-is-curlopt-post-option-required this is done automatically.