# Uploading file using PHP Curl to another server

Tags: php, django, curl, post

I am trying currently to accomplish the following:

I have a server, where a PHP-Application is running on. I have to extract some files and send them to another server (Django) with a POST request. I am trying to accomplish this by using cURL. I already have a couple of POST requests running and they all work as needed, but as soon as I try to accomplish this with a file I am running into issues.

When I try to send a file from Javascript to my Django Server with Multipart and FormData, everything works.

I tried to use the following code in PHP:

```
public function httpPost($url, $data, $multipart) {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        if ($multipart) {
            // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));    
            // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $file_handle);
        } else {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        }
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        if ($response === false) {
            var_dump(curl_error($curl));
        }
        curl_close($curl);
}
```

As you can see from the above code-snippet, I am trying to set the Header to Multipart and set the data accordingly.

I tried the following things already:

- load the file into PHP with fopen/fread then set it in the `$data` array. Then the file also appears kind of on the Django Server, but in the `request.POST` vars and not in the `request.FILES` vars.
- load the file into a `CurlFile`. Then only the file path appears on the Django Server

Always when I set multipart, the Django server can't parse the `request.BODY`.

Can anybody help here?

Comment: did you try `$file = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);` `$post = array('file_contents'=> $file)`;?

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post)`

Comment: I think so, but I will try it again.

Comment: let me know if it works, I will add it as an answer. :)

Comment: Yes i tried it before and it did not work. But I just figured out how it worked:
If I set `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);` before I set the POSTFIELDS then it works, if I do it after, then it doesn't work. I am pretty bad with PHP but does that make sense?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728740/curlopt-post-vs-curlopt-postfields-is-curlopt-post-option-required