# PHP cURL with post data login not working where wget with shell_exec is

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to access remote files on a website that requires me to log in to it. The current way I'm doing this is with a wget ran from shell_exec. This 'works' but is definitly not the way I want to do it in. I would prefer to do it using cURL, but for some reason this will not work for me.

What happens instead of getting the page I requested is I'm redirected to the login page, which does not happen with the wget method, which should be making the exact same request...

What am I doing wrong?

First of all this is the current (not nice but) working method of accessing the page:

```
shell_exec("wget --post-data='serviceLoginUser=something&serviceLoginPass=something&qq=login' -p https://internal.website.com/somepage.php?get=request -O return.json");
```

This is my download function which does not work but I want to replace the old way with: (updated after suggestion from Abkarino)

```
     public function download($url, $postData = NULL){
        //Set cURL options
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        //To act like a normal browser (needed for intranet)
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        //TODO: remove
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        //If POST data was supplied:
        if ($postData != NULL){
            curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        }

        //execute post
        return curl_exec($this->ch);
    }
```

Where the following code will form the request: (currenly this code is only to test if the cURL actually returns the correct data)

```
include 'Downloader.php';
$dl = new Downloader;
$postData = array(
    'serviceLoginUser' => 'something',
    'serviceLoginPass' => 'something',
    'qq' => 'login'
);
echo $dl->download("https://internal.website.com/somepage.php?get=request", $postData);
```

Comment: I would suggest trying the following:
1- Remove `curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));` 
 as instructed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26772699/3399564
2- Pass the array rather than a string.
Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sadly this doesn't work for me. Though on my test page I got the same result as with my own code (and this way is a nicer way). But on the page I want to use the same problem presists.

Comment: `$this->ch` may be reused with incorrect curl-options. Have to see the difference of http-headers in both cases. For instance, create a script that outputs all incoming headers to a client.

Comment: It is not used anywhere else currently. Also it is only on this specific domain (which is not stated here because it is a private page anyways) where it does not work. So it would be very unlikely that that would be the problem if it were used elsewhere. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: the only difference I see is `user-agent` (`wget` has `Wget/x.xx (linux-gnu)`). Maybe changing it would be a solution. The `-p` `wget` parameter looks weird for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this doesn't work. I actually contacted the administrator, and he said there were no useragent checks. He also said curl should just work, but he does not plan on helping me with this problem so I'm still stuck.