# Not working after moving to production server, no error, empty response

Tags: php, curl

I am attempting to use PHP cURL's functions to interact with an API I made. It worked fine on my development machine:

```
    function handleErrors(int $errSeverity , string $errMsg, string $errFile, int $errLine) {

$credentials = array(
"grant_type" => "password",
"username" => "user",
"Password" => "pass"
);

$errorObj = array (
"AppID" => 2,
"ErrorSource" => $errFile . " Line, " . $errLine,
"ErrorMessage" => $errMsg
);


$curl = curl_init();
try {
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => API_BASE . API_AUTH_PATH,
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($credentials)
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$token = json_decode($resp, true)["access_token"];


curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => API_BASE . API_ERROR_PATH,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Bearer $token"),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($errorObj)
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);

} catch (Exception $ex) {

}
finally {
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

I received the token that I use for authorization and the error was appropriately posted to the database.

However, when I moved the code over to the production server (which also hosts the API), it is no longer working. I am not getting my "token" back.

curl_error returns an empty string. $resp is empy as well. Retrieving CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT outputs something similar to the following:

```
    POST /dev_api/token HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 66
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I tried retrieving the CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE and it returned a 301, yet CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL returned the appropriate URL (I tried it in a browser).

Comment: make sure that the hostname part of API_BASE can be resolved from your server. `$ nslookup www.example.com`

Comment: What is the PHP version of your production server? `finally` was added in PHP 5.5, I believe.

Comment: I tried nslookup on the server; it appeared to resolve correctly. The production server is running PHP 7. Thanks.

Comment: A 301 is a redirect, have you tried CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION?

Comment: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION returns an empty string/nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Guessing POST converted to GET on redirect. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225409/how-to-switch-from-post-to-get-in-php-curl) and [this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTREDIR.html). Set this to 'duplicate of' should that answer describe your issue. Quick test with adding: `curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');`

Comment: I tried setting the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST to "POST", and also (after reading one of the articles) setting CURLOPT_POSTREDIR with no success. Thanks though.

Comment: Can we see an HTTP trace? It doing more than 5 redirects or something goofy?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure how I would trace the path the code's request takes?

Comment: After setting the output to verbose and directing it to a file, it seems as if there is some issue with the certificate (subject name does not match target host name). Not really sure why since it worked locally (and the website itself does not even use HTTPS), but that is what the output indicates.