# Internal api call changes $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] to GET

Tags: php

We recently changed our app to be compatible with SSL/Https.  We have an internal api that calls a function on the same server with the url such as https://news.hubsdev.com/admministrator/index.php?option=com_api&task=mail.listcreate.  This stopped working, I believe because $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] changes to GET from POST when the api is run.
Is there a way for me to change this to POST, or prevent it from changing to GET?  The code I use to execute the api is below. We recently put in the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION because the api was returning 301 errors after the switch to ssl.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `CURLOPT_POST` expects boolean I think.

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225409/how-to-switch-from-post-to-get-in-php-curl

Comment: I did not see that question - I am having the same issue only it is changing to GET from POST.  I was not sure if it was a good idea to set it to POST with someting like  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

Comment: This is a different question than the one marked as dupe above

Comment: Yes, it is. Just trying to be helpful and offer some resources

Comment: I was directing that to Quentin, because he had marked this as a dupe

Comment: I added         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
 and it works great!